# Как вывести только те новости, которые принадлежат к определенной категории?

Tags: php, mysql

Вообщем ситуация в том, чтобы в блоке вывести только те новости, которые принадлежат к определенной категории. Уже долго сижу над этим, но не могу сообразить. Вот несколько ссылок на мой код, чтобы немного прояснить ситуацию. Ссылка на [Блок с категориями и отображением всех Item](http://joxi.net/a2Xnbq8cXzNGrg), [Controller](http://joxi.net/EA44WR8CezdlAb), [ItemsModel](http://joxi.net/8AnbdJPtLM11AO), [CategoryModel](http://joxi.ru/5mdB4ObCEMxXA1), [Mysql таблица категорий](http://joxi.ru/KAxJxvPU79Kgm8), [Mysql таблица Items](http://joxi.ru/nAyJk0PUoqayrZ), [Smarty шаблон](http://joxi.ru/V2V34Nyc6l8eAv).

Заранее спасибо!

Для удобства добавляю код в сам вопрос:
MainController:

```
class MainController implements \Interfaces\ControllersInterface
{
  public function index()
  {
    global $smarty;
    $news = CategoriesModel::getAll();
    $items = [];
    foreach ($news as $new){
        $id = $new['category_id'];
        $items**[$id]**[] = ItemsModel::getItemsByCategoryId($id);
    }
    $smarty->assign('items', $items);
    $smarty->assign('news', $news);
    $smarty->display('main.tpl');

  }
}
```

CategoriesModel:

```
class CategoriesModel{
    public static function getAll()
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY weight DESC";
    $db = DB::getConnection();
    return $db->query($query)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

public static function getCategoryId()
{
    $query = "SELECT category_id FROM categories";
    $db = DB::getConnection();
    return $db->query($query)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

public static function getItemsByCategoryId($id)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE category_id = '$id'";
    $db = DB::getConnection();
    return $db->query($query)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
}
```

ItemsModel:

```
class ItemsModel{
public $name;
public $description;
public $category_id;

public static function itemsList()
{
    $db = DB::getConnection();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM items";
    return $db->query($query)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

public static function getSingleItem($id)
{
    $db = DB::getConnection();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = '$id'";
    return $db->query($query)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

public static function getItemsByCategoryId($id)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE category_id = '$id'";
    $db = DB::getConnection();
    return $db->query($query)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
}
```

Шаблон где происходит вывод:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="label label-info"><a href="/news">Show all latest news</a></div><br /><br />
    {foreach $news as $article}
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">{$article["name"]}</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            {foreach $items*[$article["category_id"]* as $it}
                {foreach $it as $i}
                    {$i["name"]}
                {/foreach}
            {/foreach}
        </div>
    </div>
    {/foreach}
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте код в вопрос (php и пример БД).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проиндексируйте `$items` по id категории, заполняя массив таким образом: `$items[$id] = ItemsModel::getItemsByCategoryId($id);`. А в шаблоне, внутри цикла `{foreach $news as $article}` обходите не все `$items`, а только `$items[$article['id']]`.